# Extracting overlaping pairs of rows from df with two columns

Tags: r

I would like to find out which pairs overlap between these two tables:

```
> dput(data1)
structure(list(Name.x = c("MDH1", "MDH1", "IDH2", "IDH2", "IDH2", 
"IDH2", "IDH2", "IDH2", "IDH2", "SCOALB", "SCOALB", "CSY4", "CSY4", 
"CSY4", "CSY4", "CSY4", "FUM1", "FUM1", "IDH6", "IDH6", "IDH6", 
"ODC1-1", "ODC1-1", "ODC1-1", "ODC1-1", "ODC1-1", "ODC2-1", "ODC2-1", 
"ODC2-1", "ACO2", "IDH1", "IDH1", "IDH1", "IDH1", "ODC2-2"), 
    Name.y = c("SCOALB", "SCOALA-1", "CSY4", "IDH6", "ODC1-1", 
    "ODC2-1", "IDH1", "ODC2-2", "ODC1-2", "SCOALA-1", "SCOALA-2", 
    "IDH6", "SDH2-1", "IDH1", "IDH5", "ICDH", "ODC1-1", "ODC1-2", 
    "ACO2", "IDH1", "IDH5", "ODC2-1", "IDH1", "IDH5", "ODC2-2", 
    "ODC1-2", "IDH1", "ODC2-2", "ODC1-2", "IDH1", "IDH5", "SCOALA-2", 
    "ODC2-2", "ODC1-2", "ODC1-2")), .Names = c("Name.x", "Name.y"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))



> dput(data2)
    structure(list(Protein1 = structure(c(3L, 7L, 18L, 19L, 7L, 19L, 
    6L, 18L, 6L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 9L, 8L, 19L, 18L, 9L, 7L, 18L, 12L, 
    8L, 19L, 5L, 29L, 12L, 29L, 12L, 18L, 7L, 17L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 19L, 
    12L, 3L, 19L, 16L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 29L, 12L, 7L, 29L, 
    18L, 16L, 18L, 29L, 8L, 17L, 16L, 17L, 12L, 6L, 8L, 17L, 29L, 
    9L, 17L, 29L, 19L, 8L, 17L, 29L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 29L, 29L, 19L, 
    19L, 19L, 29L, 12L, 19L, 17L, 29L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 19L, 16L, 4L, 
    1L, 5L, 17L, 9L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 16L, 29L, 7L, 12L, 
    8L, 4L, 29L, 12L, 5L), .Label = c("ACO2", "ACO3", "CSY4", "FUM1", 
    "ICDH", "IDH1", "IDH2", "IDH5", "IDH6", "LPD1", "LPD2", "MDH1", 
    "MDH2", "ME1", "ME2", "ODC1-1", "ODC1-2", "ODC2-1", "ODC2-2", 
    "PDC1a-1", "PDC1a-2", "PDC1b", "PDC2-1", "PDC2-2", "SCoALa-1", 
    "SCoALa-2", "SCoALb", "SDH1-1", "SDH2-1", "SDH2-2", "SDH2-3", 
    "SDH3-1", "SDH4", "SDH5", "SDH6", "SDH7a", "SDH7b", "SDH8"), class = "factor"), 
        Protein2 = structure(c(1L, 6L, 7L, 17L, 1L, 16L, 3L, 9L, 
        1L, 5L, 17L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 5L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 
        4L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 
        9L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 16L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 
        1L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 17L, 29L, 3L, 8L, 
        6L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 5L, 19L, 12L, 5L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 19L, 
        4L, 18L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
        4L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 16L, 12L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 8L, 5L), .Label = c("ACO2", 
        "ACO3", "CSY4", "FUM1", "ICDH", "IDH1", "IDH2", "IDH5", "IDH6", 
        "LPD1", "LPD2", "MDH1", "MDH2", "ME1", "ME2", "ODC1-1", "ODC1-2", 
        "ODC2-1", "ODC2-2", "PDC1a-1", "PDC1a-2", "PDC1b", "PDC2-1", 
        "PDC2-2", "SCoALa-1", "SCoALa-2", "SCoALb", "SDH1-1", "SDH2-1", 
        "SDH2-2", "SDH2-3", "SDH3-1", "SDH4", "SDH5", "SDH6", "SDH7a", 
        "SDH7b", "SDH8"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Protein1", 
    "Protein2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 4L, 6L, 
    12L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 33L, 44L, 48L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 60L, 68L, 70L, 
    72L, 76L, 86L, 109L, 110L, 119L, 133L, 144L, 146L, 158L, 170L, 
    197L, 202L, 206L, 211L, 213L, 226L, 227L, 237L, 271L, 272L, 286L, 
    290L, 297L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 319L, 323L, 327L, 347L, 348L, 351L, 
    357L, 370L, 372L, 373L, 378L, 379L, 392L, 406L, 410L, 414L, 417L, 
    419L, 437L, 442L, 445L, 448L, 455L, 457L, 462L, 471L, 479L, 482L, 
    483L, 488L, 503L, 509L, 522L, 536L, 563L, 618L, 620L, 623L, 628L, 
    630L, 644L, 647L, 666L, 668L, 673L, 676L, 678L, 679L, 690L, 691L, 
    694L, 698L, 703L, 709L, 714L, 715L, 722L, 723L, 724L, 727L, 739L, 
    740L))
```

In each of `df` there are two columns which store strings. Strings overlap between table. However, the order between pairs might be different. One string from the pair might be find in first column of `data1` and in second column in `data2`. How to find what pairs and how many of them overlap between datasets ?

Comment: Share the desired output

Comment: Do you mean to match: `a, b` with `c, a` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> data1$combine = as.character(interaction(data1$Name.x, data1$Name.y))
> data2$combine = as.character(interaction(data2$Protein1, data2$Protein2))
> 
> dat.overlap = data1[complete.cases(match(data2$combine, data1$combine)),]
> dat.overlap
     Name.x   Name.y         combine
2      MDH1 SCOALA-1   MDH1.SCOALA-1
4      IDH2     IDH6       IDH2.IDH6
11   SCOALB SCOALA-2 SCOALB.SCOALA-2
13     CSY4   SDH2-1     CSY4.SDH2-1
18     FUM1   ODC1-2     FUM1.ODC1-2
28   ODC2-1   ODC2-2   ODC2-1.ODC2-2

data1[complete.cases(match(data1$combine, data2$combine)),]
   Name.x Name.y       combine
3    IDH2   CSY4     IDH2.CSY4
7    IDH2   IDH1     IDH2.IDH1
19   IDH6   ACO2     IDH6.ACO2
20   IDH6   IDH1     IDH6.IDH1
21   IDH6   IDH5     IDH6.IDH5
23 ODC1-1   IDH1   ODC1-1.IDH1
24 ODC1-1   IDH5   ODC1-1.IDH5
27 ODC2-1   IDH1   ODC2-1.IDH1
29 ODC2-1 ODC1-2 ODC2-1.ODC1-2
35 ODC2-2 ODC1-2 ODC2-2.ODC1-2
```

Comment: Does this match when data1 is `a, b`, and data2 is `b, a`?

Comment: That is a question what I wanted to ask as well.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver so the question is to you: would you match those or not?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question. I want to find pairs, order does not matter. If `a` comes first in one data and second in next data and the partner is the same it should match.

Answer (score 2):

Sort row-wise and make a key by pasting, then merge:

```
data1$key <- apply(data1, 1, function(i) paste(sort(i), collapse = "_"))
data2$key <- apply(data2, 1, function(i) paste(sort(i), collapse = "_"))
res <- merge(data1, data2, by = "key")

head(res)
#         key Name.x Name.y Protein1 Protein2
# 1 ACO2_IDH1   ACO2   IDH1     IDH1     ACO2
# 2 ACO2_IDH6   IDH6   ACO2     IDH6     ACO2
# 3 CSY4_ICDH   CSY4   ICDH     ICDH     CSY4
# 4 CSY4_IDH1   CSY4   IDH1     IDH1     CSY4
# 5 CSY4_IDH2   IDH2   CSY4     IDH2     CSY4
# 6 CSY4_IDH5   CSY4   IDH5     IDH5     CSY4
```